# How to migrate IdentityServer Bearer Token Authentication from asp.net to .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Below is the existing asp.net framework code, I tried multiple ways to convert the same code to .net core but it is not working as expected. please suggest some solution.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, IntrospectionEndpointHandler introspectionEndpointHandler)
{
  //Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
  app.CreatePerOwinContext(UserDbContext.Create);
  app.CreatePerOwinContext<UserManager>(UserManager.Create);
  app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager>(RoleManager.Create);
  JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

  // I am not able to find equlant method for UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication in . net core 
  app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
  {
    Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["identityServerUrl"],
    ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
    IntrospectionHttpHandler = introspectionEndpointHandler,
    BackchannelHttpHandler = introspectionEndpointHandler,
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceName"],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret"],
    RequiredScopes = new[]
    {
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testScope"]
    }
  });

  app.Use<ServiceProvisionMiddleware>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best shot is to install [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/3.1.6?_src=template) together with [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet) and, of course, [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.6?_src=template).

Probably the equivalent methond (not the exact same semantics, though) is [`AddJwtBearer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

When I setup Jwt in ASPnet core, I do it like this:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
  // (...)

  // identity
  services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        
  // authentication
  services.AddAuthentication( options => {
           options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer( options => {
           options.Authority = "my-authority",
           options.BackchannelHttpHandler = myCustomHttpHandler,
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
               ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
               IssuerSigningKey = "my-super-secure-secret",
               ValidateIssuer = true,
               ValidIssuer = "my-issuer",
               ValidateAudience = true,
               ValidAudience = "my-audience"
           };
       });
```